Should personal hardships be mentioned in a personal statement?
I moved between my BSc and my MSc to a different country, where I had a bit of a culture shock which hurt my grades on a few key courses. I then had to work to fund myself, and another bunch of key courses suffered.
I compensated my the MSc thesis, with full marks (luckly, it had high weight). This means that my overall GPA is not terrible (3.66/4). However, the programme explicitly states that they care about relevant courses.
What is your view? Do these personal hardships matter/should I mention them?

Whatever you do, I would recommend against calling these common things "personal hardships" in your application.

@XanderHenderson Moving abroad, having some culture shock and having to work, does not count as an experience so traumatic it might sound fabricated in my book.

@Anyon sure, but the solution is the same.

What you describe doesn't sound like something extraordinary or even worth mentioning. Most people have to fund themselves and change countries from time to time. So I would recommend to focus on your actual accomplishments and not on excuses why they are less optimal than you would like them to be.

What actually matters is your preparation and your likelihood of success in a doctoral program and thereafter. Some places (US) this needs to be "verified" via letters of recommendation of people who can honestly predict success.
So, while stating that you succeeded even though your path was rough isn't a bad thing, it probably counts for less than other things. Many students overcome difficulties.
And, if you can get a letter writer to say such things, rather than saying them yourself, it has more credence.
If this is a formal Statement of Purpose, then focus it on the future, not the difficulties of the past. Focus on your goals and on your ability to work hard to achieve them. In a separate "Personal Statement" you can mention that you've worked through some difficult times to get to where you are, but don't expect it to have a large effect.
